# Restrict url from direct access from browser in lumen

Tags: angularjs, .htaccess, security, lumen, protected

I want to disallow user to access video from direct url using bowser

```
<video src="MYURL" type="video/mp4" >
    <track src="http://www.videogular.com/assets/subs/pale-blue-dot.vtt" 
           kind="subtitles" srclang="en" label="English">
</video>
```

Above code is correct but if someone copy MYURL from inspect element in browser and try to access in new tab with direct MYURL i want to restrict them to do so.

Technology
Frontend : angularjs
Backend : lumen (api)

Comment: Angular doesn't really have anything to do with it are you talking about restricting access to resources using lumen?  Are users authorized in your application?  Best you can do easily is use authorization in your lumen route handlers to restrict to logged in users but doesn't mean they can't download the content.  In order to really protect video you need some sort of video streaming server that can protect the content... you'll want to look into video copy protection https://www.wowza.com/blog/a-note-on-html5

Comment: A savvy user/interested party could use something like Charles or Wireshark to get any data sent to the client, without some sort of more advanced encryption or copy protection there's no way to stop someone from getting data you plan to send out.